# Iterate through model columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure the best way to iterate through all the columns within my Day model to benefit a simplified formatting scheme.

`index.html.erb`

```
<% @day.each do |u| %>
    <li id="date"><%= clean_date(u.date) %></li>
    <li><b>Morning</b>: <%= u.morning %></li>
    <% unless u.morning_notes.blank? %><li><b>Morning Notes</b>: <%= u.morning_notes %><% end %></li>
    <li><b>Afternoon</b>: <%= u.afternoon %></li>
    <% unless u.afternoon_notes.blank? %><li><b>Afternoon Notes</b>: <%= u.afternoon_notes %><% end %></li>
    <li><b>Evening</b>: <%= u.evening %></li>
    <% unless u.evening_notes.blank? %><li><b>Evening Notes</b>: <%= u.evening_notes %><% end %></li>
    <li><b>Night</b>: <%= u.night %></li>
    <% unless u.night_notes.blank? %><li><b>Night Notes</b>: <%= u.night_notes %><% end %></li>
<% end %>
```

Ideally, it'd be something like:

```
<% @day.each do |u| %>
    <li id="date"><%= clean_date(u.date) %></li>
    <li><b>TimeOfDay</b>: <%= u.TimeOfDay %></li>
    <% unless u.TimeOfDay_notes.blank? %>
      <li><b>TimeOfDay Notes</b>: <%= u.TimeOfDay_notes %>
    <% end %></li>
<% end %>
```

Where TimeOfDay iterates through Morning, Afternoon, Evening and Night.

Comment: Does date have to be an H3? Why not just set each class to the column name and style with CSS?

Comment: Good point.  Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
<% @day.each do |u| %>
<li id="date"><%= clean_date(u.date) %></li>
<% ["morning", "afternoon", "evening", "night"].each do |t| %>
    <li><b><%= t.capitalize %></b>: <%= u.send(t) %></li>
    <% notes = u.send("#{t}_notes") %>
    <% unless notes.blank? %>
        <li><b><%= t.capitalize %> Notes</b>: <%= notes %></li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I should add though that I would probably move this to the model or the controller, so the view has a nice neatly packaged object or hash to deal with.

Comment: Yup! This works great.  Just have to remove the "u" from the "unless" line.  What's the best way to transfer this to the model?

Comment: It's hard to say exactly because I don't really get what u.morning is.  The most overkill solution I can think of would be to define a separate class inside your Day class, say, say `class TimeData; attr_accessor :time, :notes; end`, and to have an instance method in Day that returns a hash of these things, indexed by :morning, :afternoon, etc.  Then the loop above would go in that method.  But if your don't need it elsewhere, then I'd probably just have a method like `def time_notes; {morning => morning_notes, :afternoon => afternoon_notes, ...}` and use an each_pair loop in your view.